# Discriminative Learning Rates for Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I wish to apply different learning rates for each layer (as is done in Fastai) for Keras. All I have found in coming close to this is by modifying this line `self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))` in the [keras code block found here](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/#a-first-simple-example) by multiplying the gradients with its corresponding learning rate (and set the global learning rate to 1).

However, this method would only work with SGD and other simple optimizers as things such as momentum would distort this simple multiplication of the gradient.

Here is ideally how I would like to implement it:

```py
# example data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 784).astype("float32") / 255.0
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 784).astype("float32") / 255.0

lrs = [1e-2, 1e-1]
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, input_dim=784, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lrs), # DOESNT WORK
    loss="mean_squared_error",
    metrics=["mean_absolute_error"],
)
```

Any thoughts on how I could implement this. Another idea is to have the same number of optimizers as learning rates, and to update them in the `train_step` function inside the custom model.

Comment: I don't think Keras/TF support that in a built-in way. However, [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/pull/396) and [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/pull/969) PRs on Github might give you some ideas (if you haven't already seen them).

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using tensorflow addons now.

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

```
optimizers = [Adam(learning_rate=1e-2),
              Adam(learning_rate=1e-1)]
    
#specifying the optimizers and layers in which it will operate
optimizers_and_layers = [
        (optimizers[0], model.layers[0]),
        (optimizers[1], model.layers[1]),
    ]
```

```
# Using Multi Optimizer from Tensorflow Addons
opt = tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer(optimizers_and_layers)
```

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=opt, 
    loss="mean_squared_error",
    metrics=["mean_absolute_error"],
)
```

Comment: May I use the `Functional` object (the pre-trained model) as the second parameter of the tuple that declares the corresponding layer of the optimizer to cover all layers of the pre-trained model?